# Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user . This happens when ItemBeingAdded but works fine on itemwasadded

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm deploying a sharepoint add in for SharePoint Online.

As the title says when using itembeingadded event receiver i get error that item does not exist.

This is my code for the event receiver :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.EventReceivers;

namespace LeaveRequestAppWeb.Services
{
public class CalculateWorkDaysBeingAdded : IRemoteEventService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles events that occur before an action occurs, such as when a user adds or deletes a list item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties">Holds information about the remote event.</param>
    /// <returns>Holds information returned from the remote event.</returns>
    public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

        string title = Convert.ToString(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Title"]);

        int listItemId = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId;

        Guid listId = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId;

        using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(listId);
                ListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
                item["Title"] = "apoel";
                item.Update();
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles events that occur after an action occurs, such as after a 
    user adds an item to a list or deletes an item from a list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties">Holds information about the remote event.
   </param>
    public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the below line:

```
int listItemId = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId;
```

you are trying to get the Item ID on `itembeingadded` event. Since the item is not added to the list the ID for that item is not generated by SharePoint and thus will be null.

Where as on `Itemwasadded` event the item is added to the list and ID has been generated by SharePoint for the respective item and hence your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So how can i do it ? I want on save of the item to change the value of a field. But when i use the item was added event receiver it needs a refresh in order to show the updated value. Is there a way to change the value on save of the item? (Being added)

Comment: Try properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Title"] = "apoel". See if it works, otherwise you have to use the itemwasadded event and find a way to refresh the page

Comment: I have tried properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["Title"] = "apoel" and it works ok when debugging in vs but when the item is saved the updated value is not saved .

Comment: You have to update the item as well setting the value only will not work. try as suggested here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2d4f2d92-95db-4026-8431-ab7beff84515/remote-event-receivers-itemadding-itemupdating-events?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: Yes that solution works fine! esult.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Title", "After adding");
result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;